# IOS pedometer for animal steps?

Tags: ios, iphone

I tried to record my dog steps during a walk with CMPedometer and acceleration with CMMotionManager. I attached iPhone to the dog and got mixed results: Measuring acceleration worked as expected, however counting  of steps didn't work at all. When I carry the iPhone pedometer works as expected.
Why pedometer doesn't work with a dog? Because of difference between dog and human steps? It wouldn't work for horses too, or will it work?